# Merge / Union multiple files (.csv) with different schema (columns) into single file .csv - Azure Data Factory

Tags: csv, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I want to merge / union multiple files (.csv) with different schema into a single file (.csv) using Azure Data Factory / Synapse Analytics.

Example:

File 1, schema:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 |
| 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 |

File 2, schema

| C1 | C5 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 05 | 03 |
| 01 | 05 | 03 |

File 3, schema:

| C1 | C4 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 04 | 02 |
| 01 | 04 | 02 |

**My expexted output should be:**

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 |
| 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 |
| 01 |  | 03 |  | 05 |
| 01 |  | 03 |  | 05 |
| 01 | 02 |  | 04 |  |
| 01 | 02 |  | 04 |  |

**All the files are in the same folder**

But I am having the following issue, due to some columns are not listed in all files

**{ "errorCode": "2200", "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidColumnMappingColumnNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column 'C2' specified in column mapping cannot be found in source data.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'", "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Copy_24a", "details": [] }**

I tried using Schema drift but no result as same.

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this?

**Update**

Now, I am trying Union Transformation from Data Flow. My Source is a folder where I have several/multiple files. As following:

[image]

But, still the problem. Actually, if I check the preview, the information shown is not correct:

[image]

The curious thing is when a take a look to the preview directly from the origin is looking good, as I want the result (Delimited Text):

[image]

Hope anyone could help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello @Horacio Enriquez, were you able to solve the problem? I have the same requirement, help will be much appriciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the data flow Union transformation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-union

Comment: Almost done! The fact is I want to perform a Union (to append rows).

But, I have 1 source where I have multiple/several files. I don´t want to create a source for each file. All the files are in the same folder, this folder is my source. Do you have any insights?  Thanks! @Mark Kromer MSFT

Comment: mergeSchema feature for delimitedText like CDM source will help so it can be just 1 source

Comment: @Kiran-MSFT Hi can you be more specific about “mergeSchema” ? I have more than 100 files for more than 10 types, so I have only option making it as 1 source.